# how to find cosine similarity in a pre-computed matrix with a new vector?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I have a dataframe with 5000 items(rows) and 2048 features(columns).

Shape of my dataframe is **(5000, 2048).**
when I calculate cosine matrix using pairwise distance in sklearn, I get (5000,5000) matrix. 
Here I can compare each other.

But now If I have a new vector shape of **(1,2048)**, how can find cosine similarity of this item with early dataframe which I had, using **(5000,5000)** cosine matrix which I have already calculated?

EDIT

**PS:** I can append this new vector to my dataframe and calculate again cosine similarity. But for large amount of data it gets slow. Or is there any other fast and accurate distance metrics?

Comment: shouldn't you compare your new `(1, 2048)` vector to each of the `5000` data rows?

Answer (score 0):

The initial (5000,5000) matrix encodes the similarity values of all your 5000 items in pairs (i.e. symmetric matrix).

To have the similarities in case of a new item, concatenate and make a `(5001, 2048)` matrix and then estimate similarity again to get `(5001,5001)`

In other words, you can not directly use the `(5000,5000)` precomputed matrix to get the similarity with the new `(1,2048)` vector.

Comment: I did try this method. I am struggling with the speed. Because I have not only 5000, maybe 100,000 items later. I thought maybe there's a way to compare pre-computed matrix with a new vector rather than appending new vector and calculating again. Because I need to find similar Items as fast as I can. For 5000 items it's okay. maybe there are some faster methods that you can suggest? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have also been using this for 200.000 samples and I know that it might be slow but there is no other way. I use `https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html`. Consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Since cosine similarity is symmetric. You can compute the similarity meassure with the old data matrix, that is similarity between the new sample `(1,2048)` and old matrix `(5000,2048)` this will give you a vector of `(5000,1)` you can append this vector into the column dimension of the pre-computed cosine matrix making it `(5000,5001)` now since you know the cosine similarity of the new sample to itself. you can append this similarity to itself, back into the previously computed vector making it of size `(5001,1)`, this vector you can append in the row dimension of the new cosine matrix that will make it `(5001,5001)`

Comment: how is that different from my answer?

Comment: @makis you compute the whole `5001` to `5001` cosine similarity, I proposed to compute only the new sample with the previous samples.